# How to setup a private route with react hooks and redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am in the process of setting up a private route using React Hooks and Redux. However, the change of `isAuthenticated` state is not registered in the `PrivateRoute` component. In my Redux Dev Tools, however, `isAuthenticated` switches to true.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const authStatus = useSelector((state) => state.user.isAuthenticated);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(authStatus);
  }, [authStatus]);

  return (
    // Show the component only when the user is logged in
    // Otherwise, redirect the user to /signin page
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        authStatus ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/join" />
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Comment: When do you populate isAuthenticated in redux. It could be so that you value is used before it is even ready

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri i really assume thats it. How to I wait until the value is avalailble?

Comment: Add a loading state in your reducer too

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had not passed auth as prop. Consequently, t the update in the store was not registered. Please see the fix:

```
function AuthStatus() {
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.user.isAuthenticated);
  return auth;
}


const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth = AuthStatus, ...rest }) => {


  return (
    // Show the component only when the user is logged in
    // Otherwise, redirect the user to /signin page
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        auth ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/join" />
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```